# Saving and Loading NSNumber

Tags: int, nsuserdefaults, nsnumber

Im working on a BlackJack game and I'm having trouble finding the correct way of saving and loading an int named PlayerMoney using NSNumbers and NSUserDefaults.

Here is how Im trying to load the Values

```
-(void)createSceneContents {


    //Load ---------------------------------------------------------
    NSUserDefaults *Defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber *PlayerMoneyLoad = [Defaults objectForKey:@"PlayerMoneySave"];
    self.PlayerMoney = PlayerMoneyLoad;
    NSLog(@"PlayerMoneyLoad:%@", PlayerMoneyLoad);
    NSLog(@"PlayerMoney:%@", self.PlayerMoney);
```

and here is where I try to save it

```
    //Save ---------------------------------------------------------
    NSUserDefaults *Defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber *PlayerMoneySave = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.PlayerMoney];
    [Defaults setObject:PlayerMoneySave forKey:@"PlayerMoneySave"];
    [Defaults synchronize];
```

before I added the line

```
    self.PlayerMoney = PlayerMoneyLoad;
```

Saving was working but upon loading the game the "NSNumber PlayerMoneyLoad" would not transfer the  value to the "int PlayerMoney". Now that I've added this line, when the game saves it seems to pick a random number somewhere around 150000000 any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `NSNumber` into `int`, use the the following code:

```
NSNumber number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];    //Pass integer value to NSNumber
int intNumber = [number intValue];     // Get integer value back from NSNumber
```

In this way you can convert `NSNumber` to `int`.

Comment: The use of `NSNumber` is not needed. See my answer. Even so, use modern syntax. The 1st line could simply be: `NSNumber number = @10;`. Or with a variable it would be: `NSNumber number = @(self.PlayerMoney);`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this the hard way. Read the docs for `NSUserDefaults`.

To save simply do:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:self.PlayerMoney forKey:@"PlayerMoneySave"];
```

To read simply do:

```
self.PlayerMoney = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"PlayerMoneySave"];
```

Things are always easier with the right API.